# data modeling relationships

Tags: relationships, data-model

As I am analyzing standard objects, it's quite easy to understand Accounts Related Tab shows contacts as there is a lookup relationship on the contact object on AccountID field.

On a similar understanding, I can see that Contacts Related Tab has Opportunities, but not understanding which relationship field on the Opportunity object is relating contacts & opportunities objects.

Comment: You can use the Schema Builder (in Setup) to view all objects and their relationships.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a junction object between Opportunity and Contacts called `OpportunityContactRole` as shown in the diagram below. I think that may help explain for you what you're not understanding about the data model.

[image: Sales Objects ERD]

Comment: Thanks #crmprogdev. Junction object between contact & opportunity helps me understand better, another quickie is that we can export the sales object data model from schema builder with the module selection ?

Comment: You're welcome @madajee. Community etiquette is to help others by marking your question as solved through checking the answer that resolved your issue. If you don't, it leaves the impression to anyone who searches the topic later that your question wasn't answered to your satisfaction. I don't fully understand your additional question as phrased. LucidCharts has the ability to create ERDs from Salesforce orgs. To my knowledge, schema builder doesn't have an export function. See the Salesforce Object Reference for more ERDs like the above.

Comment: I will take note of your advise. Appreciated #crmprogdev.